# How to !rm python_var (in Jupyter notebooks)

Tags: python, bash, jupyter, rm

I know I can do this:

```
CSV_Files = [file1.csv, file2.csv, etc...]

%rm file1.csv
!rm file2.csv
```

but how can I do this as a variable. eg.

```
TXT_Files = [ABC.txt, XYZ.txt, etc...]

for file in TXT_Files:
  !rm file
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the shell? `CSV_Files.map(os.remove)`

Comment: Just a newbie's peeve of not wanting to import os. Was wondering if I could do this in a loop. [os.remove(file) for file in Files] works great btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm` can remove several files per call:

```
In [80]: !touch a.t1 b.t1 c.t1
In [81]: !ls *.t1
a.t1  b.t1  c.t1
In [82]: !rm -r a.t1 b.t1 c.t1
In [83]: !ls *.t1
ls: cannot access '*.t1': No such file or directory
```

If the starting point is a list of file names:

```
In [116]: alist = ['a.t1', 'b.t1', 'c.t1']
In [117]: astr = ' '.join(alist)            # make a string
In [118]: !echo $astr                       # variable substitution as in BASH
a.t1 b.t1 c.t1
In [119]: !touch $astr                    # make 3 files
In [120]: ls *.t1
a.t1  b.t1  c.t1
In [121]: !rm -r $astr                    # remove them
In [122]: ls *.t1
ls: cannot access '*.t1': No such file or directory
```

Working with Python's own OS functions is probably better, but you can do much of the same stuff with %magics - if you understand shell well enough.

---

To use 'magics' in a Python expression, I have to use the underlying functions, not the '!' or '%' syntax, e.g.

```
import IPython
for txt in ['a.t1','b.t1','c.t1']:
    IPython.utils.process.getoutput('touch %s'%txt)
```

The `getoutput` function is used by `%sx` (which underlies `!!`) which uses `subprocess.Popen`.  But if you go to all that work you might as well use the `os` functions that Python itself provides.

---

The file names may need an added layer of quoting to ensure that the shell doesn't give a syntax error:

```
In [129]: alist = ['"a(1).t1"', '"b(2).t1"', 'c.t1']
In [130]: astr = ' '.join(alist)
In [131]: !touch $astr
In [132]: !ls *.t1
'a(1).t1'   a.t1  'b(2).t1'   b.t1   c.t1
```

Comment: that's great and all, but doesnt work in a loop.

'/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'

Comment: The magic syntax with '!' and '%' (and unquoted strings) isn't valid Python, so doesn't work within Python structures like loops.  Those expressions have to be used at top level where the IPython REPL can catch and parse them.

Comment: owh wait, it's because I have parentheses in the str (in a list). eg. `files = ['Hello(1).csv', 'Hello(2).csv']`

Comment: otherwise it works flawlessly. Thanks! it's what i wanted

Comment: You may need an added layer of quotes, e.g. `'"Hello(1).csv"'`.

Comment: ahha! `var = '"' + var + '"'` but that looks silly.... guess i'll just `import os` *laugh*

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in Python without magic shell commands. I recommend using the `pathlib` module, for a more modern approach. For what you're doing, it would be:

```
import pathlib
csv_files = pathlib.Path('/path/to/actual/files')
for csv_file in csv_files.glob('*.csv'):
    csv_file.unlink()
```

Use the `.glob()` method to filter only the files you want to use, and `.unlink()` to delete them (which is similar to `os.remove()`).

Avoid using `file` as a variable, as it's a reserved word in the language.